# What should I do in order to build curl without an error?

Tags: linux, curl, build, autoconf, autotools

This failed when I run ./buildconf

The error information is as follows:

```
[mirror@home curl]$ ls
acinclude.m4   CMakeLists.txt     GIT-INFO        MacOSX-Framework     packages       TODO-RELEASE
Android.mk     configure.ac       include         Makefile.am          perl           vc6curl.dsw
buildconf      COPYING            install-sh      Makefile.dist        README         winbuild
buildconf.bat  CTestConfig.cmake  lib             Makefile.msvc.names  RELEASE-NOTES
CHANGES        curl-config.in     libcurl.pc.in   maketgz              sample.emacs
CHANGES.0      curl-style.el      log2changes.pl  missing              src
CMake          docs               m4              mkinstalldirs        tests
[mirror@home curl]$ ./config
[mirror@home curl]$ ./buildconf
buildconf: autoconf version 2.63 (ok)
buildconf: autom4te version 2.59 (ERROR: does not match autoconf version)
[mirror@home curl]$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

```
[zack@helios ~]
$ wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.27.0.tar.gz
--2012-09-06 04:15:06--  http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.27.0.tar.gz
Resolving curl.haxx.se... 80.67.6.50, 2a00:1a28:1200:9::2
Connecting to curl.haxx.se|80.67.6.50|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3154661 (3.0M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘curl-7.27.0.tar.gz’

100%[======================================================>] 3,154,661   1.66MB/s   in 1.8s   

2012-09-06 04:15:08 (1.66 MB/s) - ‘curl-7.27.0.tar.gz’ saved [3154661/3154661]

[zack@helios ~]
$ tar xzf curl-7.27.0.tar.gz 
[zack@helios ~]
$ cd curl-7.27.0
[zack@helios ~/curl-7.27.0]
$ ls
acinclude.m4    compile         curl-style.el  ltmain.sh            maketgz        src
aclocal.m4      config.guess    depcomp        m4                   missing        tests
Android.mk      config.sub      docs           MacOSX-Framework     mkinstalldirs  vc6curl.dsw
buildconf       configure       include        Makefile             packages       winbuild
CHANGES         configure.ac    install-sh     Makefile.am          README
CMake           COPYING         lib            Makefile.in          RELEASE-NOTES
CMakeLists.txt  curl-config.in  libcurl.pc.in  Makefile.msvc.names  sample.emacs
[zack@helios ~/curl-7.27.0]
$ ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-ldap --disable-ldaps --enable-ipv6 --enable-manual --enable-versioned-symbols --enable-threaded-resolver --without-libidn --with-random=/dev/urandom --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
[snip]
checking whether hiding of library internal symbols will actually happen... yes
checking whether to enforce SONAME bump... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating docs/Makefile
config.status: creating docs/examples/Makefile
config.status: creating docs/libcurl/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: creating include/curl/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/Makefile
config.status: creating lib/libcurl.vers
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/data/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/server/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/libtest/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/unit/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/Win32/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/Win32/cygwin/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/Linux/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/Linux/RPM/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/Linux/RPM/curl.spec
config.status: creating packages/Linux/RPM/curl-ssl.spec
config.status: creating packages/Solaris/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/EPM/curl.list
config.status: creating packages/EPM/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/vms/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/AIX/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/AIX/RPM/Makefile
config.status: creating packages/AIX/RPM/curl.spec
config.status: creating curl-config
config.status: creating libcurl.pc
config.status: creating lib/curl_config.h
config.status: creating include/curl/curlbuild.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.27.0
  Host setup:       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
  SSH support:      enabled (libSSH2)
  zlib support:     enabled
  krb4 support:     no      (--with-krb4*)
  GSSAPI support:   no      (--with-gssapi)
  SPNEGO support:   no      (--with-spnego)
  TLS-SRP support:  enabled
  resolver:         threaded
  ipv6 support:     enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  ca cert path:     no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     enabled (librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTMP RTSP SCP SFTP SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

[zack@helios ~/curl-7.27.0]
$ make -j16
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/lib'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/lib'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib   -DCURL_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS   -fvisibility=hidden -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread  -c -o libcurl_la-file.lo `test -f 'file.c' || echo './'`file.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -DCURL_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS -fvisibility=hidden -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread -c file.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcurl_la-file.o
[snip]
libtool: link: (cd ".libs" && rm -f "libcurl.so" && ln -s "libcurl.so.4.2.0" "libcurl.so")
libtool: link: /usr/bin/ar cru .libs/libcurl.a  libcurl_la-file.o libcurl_la-timeval.o libcurl_la-base64.o libcurl_la-hostip.o libcurl_la-progress.o libcurl_la-formdata.o libcurl_la-cookie.o libcurl_la-http.o libcurl_la-sendf.o libcurl_la-ftp.o libcurl_la-url.o libcurl_la-dict.o libcurl_la-if2ip.o libcurl_la-speedcheck.o libcurl_la-ldap.o libcurl_la-ssluse.o libcurl_la-version.o libcurl_la-getenv.o libcurl_la-escape.o libcurl_la-mprintf.o libcurl_la-telnet.o libcurl_la-netrc.o libcurl_la-getinfo.o libcurl_la-transfer.o libcurl_la-strequal.o libcurl_la-easy.o libcurl_la-security.o libcurl_la-krb4.o libcurl_la-curl_fnmatch.o libcurl_la-fileinfo.o libcurl_la-ftplistparser.o libcurl_la-wildcard.o libcurl_la-krb5.o libcurl_la-memdebug.o libcurl_la-http_chunks.o libcurl_la-strtok.o libcurl_la-connect.o libcurl_la-llist.o libcurl_la-hash.o libcurl_la-multi.o libcurl_la-content_encoding.o libcurl_la-share.o libcurl_la-http_digest.o libcurl_la-md4.o libcurl_la-md5.o libcurl_la-curl_rand.o libcurl_la-http_negotiate.o libcurl_la-inet_pton.o libcurl_la-strtoofft.o libcurl_la-strerror.o libcurl_la-amigaos.o libcurl_la-hostasyn.o libcurl_la-hostip4.o libcurl_la-hostip6.o libcurl_la-hostsyn.o libcurl_la-inet_ntop.o libcurl_la-parsedate.o libcurl_la-select.o libcurl_la-gtls.o libcurl_la-sslgen.o libcurl_la-tftp.o libcurl_la-splay.o libcurl_la-strdup.o libcurl_la-socks.o libcurl_la-ssh.o libcurl_la-nss.o libcurl_la-qssl.o libcurl_la-rawstr.o libcurl_la-curl_addrinfo.o libcurl_la-socks_gssapi.o libcurl_la-socks_sspi.o libcurl_la-curl_sspi.o libcurl_la-slist.o libcurl_la-nonblock.o libcurl_la-curl_memrchr.o libcurl_la-imap.o libcurl_la-pop3.o libcurl_la-smtp.o libcurl_la-pingpong.o libcurl_la-rtsp.o libcurl_la-curl_threads.o libcurl_la-warnless.o libcurl_la-hmac.o libcurl_la-polarssl.o libcurl_la-curl_rtmp.o libcurl_la-openldap.o libcurl_la-curl_gethostname.o libcurl_la-gopher.o libcurl_la-axtls.o libcurl_la-idn_win32.o libcurl_la-http_negotiate_sspi.o libcurl_la-cyassl.o libcurl_la-http_proxy.o libcurl_la-non-ascii.o libcurl_la-asyn-ares.o libcurl_la-asyn-thread.o libcurl_la-curl_gssapi.o libcurl_la-curl_ntlm.o libcurl_la-curl_ntlm_wb.o libcurl_la-curl_ntlm_core.o libcurl_la-curl_ntlm_msgs.o libcurl_la-curl_sasl.o libcurl_la-curl_schannel.o libcurl_la-curl_multibyte.o libcurl_la-curl_darwinssl.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libcurl.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libcurl.la" && ln -s "../libcurl.la" "libcurl.la" )
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/lib'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/lib'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c hugehelp.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_binmode.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_bname.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cb_dbg.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cb_hdr.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cb_prg.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cb_rea.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cb_see.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cb_wrt.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_cfgable.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_convert.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_dirhie.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_doswin.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_easysrc.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_formparse.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_getparam.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_getpass.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_help.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_helpers.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_homedir.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_libinfo.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_main.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_metalink.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_mfiles.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_msgs.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_operate.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_operhlp.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_panykey.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_paramhlp.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_parsecfg.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_setopt.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_sleep.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_urlglob.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_util.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_vms.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_writeenv.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_writeout.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c tool_xattr.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c -o strtoofft.o `test -f '../lib/strtoofft.c' || echo './'`../lib/strtoofft.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c -o strdup.o `test -f '../lib/strdup.c' || echo './'`../lib/strdup.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c -o rawstr.o `test -f '../lib/rawstr.c' || echo './'`../lib/rawstr.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../src -I../lib -I../src    -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread   -c -o nonblock.o `test -f '../lib/nonblock.c' || echo './'`../lib/nonblock.c
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=link gcc  -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread     -o curl  hugehelp.o tool_binmode.o tool_bname.o tool_cb_dbg.o tool_cb_hdr.o tool_cb_prg.o tool_cb_rea.o tool_cb_see.o tool_cb_wrt.o tool_cfgable.o tool_convert.o tool_dirhie.o tool_doswin.o tool_easysrc.o tool_formparse.o tool_getparam.o tool_getpass.o tool_help.o tool_helpers.o tool_homedir.o tool_libinfo.o tool_main.o tool_metalink.o tool_mfiles.o tool_msgs.o tool_operate.o tool_operhlp.o tool_panykey.o tool_paramhlp.o tool_parsecfg.o tool_setopt.o tool_sleep.o tool_urlglob.o tool_util.o tool_vms.o tool_writeenv.o tool_writeout.o tool_xattr.o strtoofft.o strdup.o rawstr.o nonblock.o  ../lib/libcurl.la -lrt -lz  
libtool: link: gcc -g0 -O2 -Wno-system-headers -pthread -o .libs/curl hugehelp.o tool_binmode.o tool_bname.o tool_cb_dbg.o tool_cb_hdr.o tool_cb_prg.o tool_cb_rea.o tool_cb_see.o tool_cb_wrt.o tool_cfgable.o tool_convert.o tool_dirhie.o tool_doswin.o tool_easysrc.o tool_formparse.o tool_getparam.o tool_getpass.o tool_help.o tool_helpers.o tool_homedir.o tool_libinfo.o tool_main.o tool_metalink.o tool_mfiles.o tool_msgs.o tool_operate.o tool_operhlp.o tool_panykey.o tool_paramhlp.o tool_parsecfg.o tool_setopt.o tool_sleep.o tool_urlglob.o tool_util.o tool_vms.o tool_writeenv.o tool_writeout.o tool_xattr.o strtoofft.o strdup.o rawstr.o nonblock.o  ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so -lrt -lz -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/src'
Making all in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include'
Making all in curl
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include/curl'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include/curl'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include/curl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include/curl'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0/include'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zack/curl-7.27.0'
[zack@helios ~/curl-7.27.0]
$ ./src/curl --version
curl 7.27.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

That's how you do it.

Comment: You could have omitted all the output and just show the steps.

Answer (score 0):

You should just reinstall autoconf (autom4te is a dependency).